# Instalei o Unity e deu erro, não consigo visualizar a demo do jogo e nem colocar os scripts

Tags: unity3d

Esse é os erros q aparecem quando eu abro o Unity:

```
Assets/_CompletedAssets/Scripts/Helpers/RandomParticlePoint.cs(12,9): error CS0619: `UnityEngine.Component.particleSystem' is obsolete: `Property particleSystem has been deprecated. Use GetComponent<ParticleSystem>() instead. (UnityUpgradable)'
Assets/_CompletedAssets/Scripts/Helpers/RandomParticlePoint.cs(12,24): error CS1061: Type `UnityEngine.Component' does not contain a definition for `Simulate' and no extension method `Simulate' of type `UnityEngine.Component' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

E quando eu coloco um script:

```
Please fix compile errors before creating new script components.
```

Comment: Qual o projeto que você está tentando abrir?

Answer (score 1):

O primeiro erro é que você está usando um projeto antigo, e não converteu ele para funcionar no Unity 5.

O segundo é parecido, a diferença é que ele faz chamada para um método e não encontra.

Quando você responder qual o projeto que está tentando rodar, eu explico o que você precisa fazer para ele funcionar - se for possível, pois alguns projetos muito antigos estão bem defasados e o trabalho para resolver não seria plausível para um resposta no stackoverflow(mas não deve ser o caso, esse erro é comum em projetos da versão 4 que é mais recente).

Answer (score 0):

Isso acontece porque o seu **`"UnityEngine.Component.particleSystem"`** setou uma propriedade de visualização depois que você executou o seu preview. Neste caso, verifique suas extensões ou reinstale o software.